# Как мониторить добавление новостей на сайте?

Tags: node.js, парсер

Я пишу парсер на сайт новостей риа на node js и puppeteer.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let link = 'https://ria.ru/politics/';

(async () => {
    let flag = true;
    let res = [];

    try {
        let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false,
            slowMo: 100,
            devtools: true
        });

        let page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.setViewport({
            width: 1400,
            height: 1200
        });

        while (flag) {
            await page.goto(`${link}`);

            let html = await page.evaluate(async () => {
                let page = [];
                try {
                    let divs = document.querySelectorAll('div.list-item');
                    divs.forEach(div =>{ 
                        let a = div.querySelector('a.list-item__title')
                
                        let obj = {
                            title: a.innerText,
                        };
                        
                    
                

                        page.push(obj)

                    });
                }catch(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                };
                return page
            })
        
            await res.push(html) 
        
            for(let i in res) {
                if(res[i].length === 20) flag = false
            }
            console.log(res);
            
        }
        await browser.close();
        res = res.flat();
        console.log(res);


    }catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
        
})();
```

Как парсить не все новости подряд, а только что добавленные?

Comment: вносить добавленные в базу данных или кэш и сверять с тем что уже есть

Comment: @MoloF, а можете привести какой-нибудь простой пример или статью на эту тему ?